Lotto Date calculator Draw using pure javascript
By using pure javascript, i want to predict a future date and past date based on the user input date. considering lotto draw happens every wednesday and saturday at 8pm.
I have the code logic, but i need some help to finish this logic.
then main problem is to find the correct past and future dates. please help me.
function getNextLottoDraw(date) {
    
    const dayOfWeek = date.getDay(); // dayOfWeek = day of the week 0 - 6 (sun - sat)
    const hour = date.getHours(); // hour as per pm/am 
    const minute = date.getMinutes(); // Mins as mins
    

    let nextDraw = new Date(date);
    // console.log("r--->", nextDraw );

    if (dayOfWeek === 3) { // Wednesday
        if (hour < 20 || (hour === 20 && minute === 0)) {
            nextDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
            // console.log("p1--->", nextDraw );
        } else {
            nextDraw.setDate(nextDraw.getDate() + 3); // Next draw is Saturday
            // console.log("p2--->", nextDraw );
            nextDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
            // console.log("p2 22--->", nextDraw );
        }
    } else if (dayOfWeek === 6) { // Saturday
        if (hour < 20 || (hour === 20 && minute === 0)) {
            nextDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
            // console.log("W11---->", nextDraw );
        } else {
            nextDraw.setDate(nextDraw.getDate() + 4); // Next draw is Wednesday
            nextDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
            // console.log("W22---->", nextDraw );
        }
    } else {
        // console.log("else--->>");
        let daysToAdd;
        if (dayOfWeek < 3) { // Before Wednesday
            daysToAdd = 3 - dayOfWeek;
            // console.log("D11---->", daysToAdd, dayOfWeek );
        } else { // After Wednesday, before Saturday
            daysToAdd = 6 - dayOfWeek;
            // console.log("D22---->", daysToAdd, dayOfWeek  );
        }
        nextDraw.setDate(nextDraw.getDate() + daysToAdd);
        nextDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
        // console.log("last --->", nextDraw);
    }

    return nextDraw;
}

function calculateDrawDates() {
    
    const input = document.getElementById('datetime-input').value;
    const inputDate = new Date(input);
    if (isNaN(inputDate)) {
        alert('Please enter a valid date and time.');
        return;
    }
    const resultsTable = document.getElementById('results-table').querySelector('tbody');
    resultsTable.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous results

    const draws = [];
    let nextDrawDate = getNextLottoDraw(inputDate);
    console.log("result for future draws --->",nextDrawDate )

    for (let i = -2; i <= 2; i++) {
        let currentDrawDate = new Date(nextDrawDate);
        if (i < 0) {
            currentDrawDate.setDate(nextDrawDate.getDate() + i * 3); // For past dates, subtract 3 days per draw
        } else if (i > 0) {
            if(nextDrawDate.getDay() === 6) {
                currentDrawDate.setDate(nextDrawDate.getDate() + 4);
                console.log("mmm11---", currentDrawDate);
            } else {
                currentDrawDate.setDate(nextDrawDate.getDate() + 3);
                console.log("mmm22---", currentDrawDate);
            }
        }

        draws.push({
            date: currentDrawDate,
            status: currentDrawDate < inputDate ? 'Past' : 'Future'
        });
    }

    draws.forEach(draw => {
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        const dateCell = document.createElement('td');
        const statusCell = document.createElement('td');

        dateCell.textContent = draw.date.toDateString();
        statusCell.textContent = draw.status;

        row.appendChild(dateCell);
        row.appendChild(statusCell);
        row.classList.add('fade-in');

        resultsTable.appendChild(row);
    });
}




//you can just use your function getNextLottoDraw
//i've created a getPrevLottoDraw as specular clone of getNextLottoDraw

function getNextLottoDraw(date) {
    
    const dayOfWeek = date.getDay(); // dayOfWeek = day of the week 0 - 6 (sun - sat)
    const hour = date.getHours(); // hour as per pm/am 
    const minute = date.getMinutes(); // Mins as mins
    
    let nextDraw = new Date(date);
    // console.log("r--->", nextDraw );

    if (dayOfWeek === 3) { // Wednesday
        if (hour < 20 || (hour === 20 && minute === 0)) {
            nextDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
            // console.log("p1--->", nextDraw );
        } else {
            nextDraw.setDate(nextDraw.getDate() + 3); // Next draw is Saturday
            // console.log("p2--->", nextDraw );
            nextDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
            // console.log("p2 22--->", nextDraw );
        }
    } else if (dayOfWeek === 6) { // Saturday
        if (hour < 20 || (hour === 20 && minute === 0)) {
            nextDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
            // console.log("W11---->", nextDraw );
        } else {
            nextDraw.setDate(nextDraw.getDate() + 4); // Next draw is Wednesday
            nextDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
            // console.log("W22---->", nextDraw );
        }
    } else {
        // console.log("else--->>");
        let daysToAdd;
        if (dayOfWeek < 3) { // Before Wednesday
            daysToAdd = 3 - dayOfWeek;
            // console.log("D11---->", daysToAdd, dayOfWeek );
        } else { // After Wednesday, before Saturday
            daysToAdd = 6 - dayOfWeek;
            // console.log("D22---->", daysToAdd, dayOfWeek  );
        }
        nextDraw.setDate(nextDraw.getDate() + daysToAdd);
        nextDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
        // console.log("last --->", nextDraw);
    }

    return nextDraw;
}

function getPrevLottoDraw(date) {
    
    const dayOfWeek = date.getDay(); // dayOfWeek = day of the week 0 - 6 (sun - sat)
    const hour = date.getHours(); // hour as per pm/am 
    const minute = date.getMinutes(); // Mins as mins
    console.dir({dayOfWeek:dayOfWeek,hour:hour,minute:minute,});
    let prevDraw = new Date(date);
    if (dayOfWeek === 3) { // Wednesday
        if (hour > 20 || (hour === 20 && minute === 0)) {
            prevDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            prevDraw.setDate(prevDraw.getDate() - 4); // Prev draw is Saturday
            prevDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    } else if (dayOfWeek === 6) { // Saturday
        if (hour > 20 || (hour === 20 && minute === 0)) {
            prevDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            prevDraw.setDate(prevDraw.getDate() - 3); // Prev draw is Wednesday
            prevDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    } else {
        
        let daysToSubtract;
        if (dayOfWeek < 3) { // Before Wednesday
            daysToSubtract = 4 - (3 - dayOfWeek);
        } else { // After Wednesday, before Saturday
            daysToSubtract = dayOfWeek-3;
        }
        prevDraw.setDate(prevDraw.getDate() - daysToSubtract);
        prevDraw.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    return prevDraw;
}


function calculateDrawDates(inputDate) {
    const resultsTable = document.getElementById('results-table').querySelector('tbody');
    resultsTable.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous results
    let draws=[];
    let nextDrawDate = inputDate;
        let prevDrawDate = inputDate;
    for (let i = -2; i <= 2; i++) {
        //here is your new loop:
        nextDrawDate= getNextLottoDraw(nextDrawDate);
                prevDrawDate= getPrevLottoDraw(prevDrawDate);
        
        //this insert as last
        draws.push({
            date: new Date(nextDrawDate),
            status: 'Future'
        });
                //this insert as first
                draws.unshift({
            date: new Date(prevDrawDate),
            status: 'Past'
        });
                prevDrawDate.setDate(prevDrawDate.getDate()-1);
                nextDrawDate.setDate(nextDrawDate.getDate()+1);
    }

    draws.forEach(draw => {
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        const dateCell = document.createElement('td');
        const statusCell = document.createElement('td');

        dateCell.textContent = draw.date.toDateString();
        statusCell.textContent = draw.status;

        row.appendChild(dateCell);
        row.appendChild(statusCell);
        row.classList.add('fade-in');

        resultsTable.appendChild(row);
    });
}

//test:
let d1=new Date();
/*
d1.setDate(d1.getDate()-2);
let d2=getPrevLottoDraw(d1);
d2.setDate(d2.getDate()-1);
console.dir(getPrevLottoDraw(d1));
console.dir(getPrevLottoDraw(d2));
*/
calculateDrawDates(d1);
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table id="results-table">
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>



